# Comparsion of captured traffic in pcap

Tags: wireshark, capture, pcap, measure, sniffing

I'm facing a problem that I can't figure out.

**My goal:** Compare pcaps and measure the loss in capture.
**Scenario:** I've sent data (1,5 GB file) from laptop A via WiFi to shared directory on laptop B. On laptop A I've ran Wireshark capture on sending wlan adapter (in promiscuose mode). Between these laptops I have a sniffer (router with wlan in monitor mode) that captures the WiFi traffic in monitor mode = raw 802.11 frames. After file transfer was done I stop capturing on both devices. Now, what I want to do is to compare these two pcap files a measure the frame/packet/data loss = If I captured all data with sniffer and how many of them are missing. Problem is, that pcap from laptop A contains packets with TCP protocols and other.. but the pcap from sniffer contains raw frames (no protocols). I captured handshake and I know my WiFi password so I'm able to decrypt some traffic to see packet and protocols like tcp.

So my **question** is, how can I compare/measure caputred traffic (data transfer) from these two pcap files? Is it possible to folow sequence numbers and compare them?

Pcap file from laptop A have 1,7 GB and file from sniffer have 1,3 GB .So when transfered file have 1,5 GB I assume that I did not captured all traffic, but I need to now how many frames/packets I missed.

Answer (score 0):

Data packets that you are capturing in monitor mode will have fake ethernet headers. So the question how many frames have been lost at a sniffer is not really relevant. For the same data packet captured on wlan you may have a different number of data packets with 802.11 header captured at a sniffer (some captured, some lost). The only thing you can measure is how much data was send and was captured. Try loading pcap files in Wireshark, filtering out to remove beacon junk, and exporting only data portion at a sniffer. Then compare data portions at wlan interface and exported data size from a sniffer capture.